# password view when app come back foreground from background

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, background, foreground

I am developing  an app that need password  when app first launch or come back from background to foreground. 
First launch is easy. But when app back to foreground from background ,after input password ,how to back to the view last visited?
Help me please!
I want to add a password UIView in appDelegate at top of all , but i don't know how to do it. Is this right way ?

```
let pwview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
pwview.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(pwview)
```

this does not work.

Comment: Do you want to show the password view for the user to enter when app app is opened after going to background right?

Comment: @rajtharan-g Yes. And after input correct password , the app can display the view which user last visited .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the app delegate's method to handle this.

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
   // Called when app comes to foreground
}

extension UIApplication {

class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
  return topViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
}
if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
  if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
    return topViewController(base: selected)
  }
}
if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
  return topViewController(base: presented)
}
return base
}

}
```

You can use the above method from app delegate to get the top view controller and present over it.

Comment: Yes , I know I can handle it in this method , but I do not know how to add a UIView at top of all other views , and how to back to the viewContrllor the user last visit.

Answer (score 0):

Create a pwViewController with the pwview and present it from the current view controller

```
viewController.present(pwViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then dismiss it again when you are logged in